# Consulta SQL no se ejecuta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla[textos] en phpmyadmin de este modo:

Column[columna1] -> Type[int(20)] -> Null[no] --> Default[None]

Column[columna2] -> Type[text]    -> Null[no] --> Default[None]

.
.
.

La primera columna la uso como key primaria.
Mi intencion es simplemente añadir una linea nueva, este es el codigo que tengo dispuesto en dos archivos php.

Archivo1.php
php

```
$dbhost="localhost";    // host del MySQL (generalmente localhost)

$dbusuario="usuario1";      // Nombre de usuario para la BD

$dbpassword="123456";   // password del usuario

$db="BD1";          // Nombre de la BD


    function EjecutarSQL($query){
     global     $dbhost,$dbusuario,$dbpassword,$db;
     $conexion = mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
     mysql_select_db($db, $conexion);
     $resp=mysql_query($query,$conexion);
     mysql_close($conexion);
     return $resp;
    }
```

archivo2.php

```
    <?php
     require_once APP_ROOT_DIR . '/archivo1.php';
    $Var1=$array1['colum1'];
    EjecutarSQL("INSERT INTO `textos` (`columna1`) VALUES ($Var1)");
    ?>
```

El caso es que la sentencia se ejecuta pero no se crea la linea en la base de datos. Si añado un echo($query) en la funcion EjecutarSQL este me devuelve una linea que es correcta y si copio-pego esta linea en phpmyadmin se ejecuta y añade la linea en la tabla correctamente. 
No entiendo por que por codigo no funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que la sentencía que dices que se ejecuta, en realidad no lo está haciendo. El hecho de que un `echo` te devuelva la SQL no quiere decir que se esté enviando correctamente a la base de datos. Tienes la conexión bien hecha?

Comment: La funcion EjecutarSQL la utilizo en otro monton de rutinas y archivos y me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Te marca algún error en la consola del explorador? Si la conexión es correcta y la sentencia que mandas es la correcta, todo pinta que debería funcionar por ese lado.

Comment: No, no me marca nada, incluso si imprimo un echo de $resp, este sale vacio. Ahora me surge la duda de si me deveria de devolver un true.

Comment: `$resp` devuelve `true` si todo es correcto. En caso de error devuelve un `resource`. Te dejo la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php). Mete un un `echo` de `$resp` dentro de la función para ver que está ocurriendo.

Comment: no devuelve nada, añado echo('respuesta: '.$resp); justo en la linea anterior al return y el resultado:   respuesta:

Comment: En las otras rutinas que utilizas qué devuelve?

Comment: respuesta: Resource id #6 respuesta: Resource id #80

Comment: Algún tema de comillas? Lo único que diferencía esta de las otras rutinas es la sentencia que mandas.

Comment: Prueba a guardar la query en una variable y pasarla en forma de variable: `EjecutarSQL($query);`

Comment: Si, las otras sentencias son select y los resources que devuelve se resuelven con mysql_fetch_assoc. Tambien he probado lo que comentas de meter la sentencia en una variable y tampoco funciona. incluso he añadido esto:     while($Var1==''){$Var1=$Array1['colum1'];}   para asegurarme de que no se manda vacia la variable, por si hubiera algun problema de tiempos.

Comment: No tiene sentido, he realizado la misma llamada esactamente pero llamando a la sentencia mediante ajax y si que funciona.  no lo entiendo, tiene que ser algo que me impide realizar consultas desde cierta parte del servidor.

Comment: EjecutarSQL("INSERT INTO textos (columna1) VALUES ('$Var1')");

Comment: Veo varias cosas. **mysql_*** esta obsoleto y desaconsejado **se recomienda encarecidamente mysqli o PDO**, el uso de global en ese contexto es inecesario o poco recomendado, php provee funciones para ver si la conexión y la sentencia se ejecuto correctamente (**mysqli_connect_error y mysqli_error**) haz uso de ellas.

Comment: Tu código no controla absolutamente nada, por lo tanto no podrás saber dónde está fallando. Un código puede fallar porque la conexión es nula (credenciales incorrectas, etc), porque la consulta es errónea, porque el INSERT crea valores duplicados en la BD, porque hay un error en la ruta del `require`, etc, etc. Como ya se ha dicho en otros comentarios, la extensión `mysql*` es obsoleta, es recomendable actualizar tu código. También el uso de globales es un problema añadido. Basta que otro script cambie cualquiera de tus globales y ya tienes problemas.